# Let $T$ be multiplication by the matrix $A$ and find basis, kernel for the range of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be multiplication by the matrix $A$.

$$A =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 3\\
1 & 2 &  4\\
1 & 8 & 25
\end{bmatrix}  $$

My task is to find a basis for the range of $T$, and a basis for the kernel of $T$. I should also find the rank and nullity of both $T$ and $A$.

I believe that the range of $T$ equals the span of the column space of $A$. As such, I make it into its reduced row echelon form which happens to be the identity matrix. From this I take that since there is only a trivial solution for the homogenous equation $A\vec{x} = 0$, $ker(A) = \{0\}$, making the nullity $0$. From this I also take that the column vectors all are linearly independent, making all three of the column vectors a basis for the range of $T$.

This is apparently very wrong, and the correct answer should be:

A basis for the range of $T$ is $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
2\\
8
\end{bmatrix}$.

A basis for the kernel is $\begin{bmatrix}
-3\\
-7/2\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$

Making the rank of $T$ and $A = 2$ and the nullity of $T$ and $A = 1$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your answer is correct. Are you sure this is the matrix in the question? There may be a typo in your book.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Yes, I'm positive. It's 8.1.25 in Elementary Linear Algebra by Anton and Rorres, 10th edition. Unfortunately I cannot find an errata online to verify this.

Comment: One example is $A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 3 \\-1 & 2 & 4 \\1 & 8 & 31 \end{array}\right)$ to give the results above.